# Joomla "online-order" component for Joomla

Tags: joomla, components

Somebody can help me in finding an "online - ordering" component for joomla .
That can contain the following function :

1. Possibility of  creating  Form with pages  like RS!Form
2. Uploading  Files
3. Supporting Payment Gateways like  PayPal , MasterCard , WebMoney , YandexMoney ,Money Bookers , Google Checkout ... more )
4. Saving data in database. A friendly control panel  where admin can check statistics , income and expenditure, including offline transactions, and report on the data .   A good example , for what I'm looking , is this component http://www.nbill.co.uk/ , but is to expensive and complicated .

I'll be happy fore some links or advices :) .
Thank a Lot ! for all who are trying to help me ! And sorry for my bad English :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure if this is supposed to go in answer or comment but you might find this useful

http://www.rsjoomla.com/blog/3-ways-to-create-a-small-joomla-shopping-cart-with-rsformpro-and-paypal.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use virtue mart for a fully customizable component solution that's open and has lots of support. However you could just use a form that will post the url/title to the page when processing the other data as a non-payment solution (I think chrono forms does this and is free). I use breezing form for an online ordering system that does not require payment, just ordering.